# special logic gate

Tags: tikz-pgf, logic

How would one go about drawing a logic gate like this one ?

[image: not gate?]

Comment: Welcome to SE! Can you show, what you try to do so far* Otherwise your question is type "do-it-for-me" ... For minimal working example see for examples of circuits in manual for package `circuiTikZ`.

Answer (score 2):

With `circuitikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \node[american not port] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

With the TikZ `circuits.logic` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  circuits.logic,
  circuits.logic.US
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
  \node[not gate] (n) {};
  \draw (n.input) -- +(-.1,0);
  \draw (n.output) -- +(.1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Although the logical result is equal, OP's figure is like `\node[buffer gate, logic gate inputs=i] (n) {};` and not like a `not gate`